# Creating Registration Page Using ASP.NET MVC by using ADO.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Hey I stucked in creating Registration page using asp.net MVC by using ADO.net or Enterprise library.
I dont want to use the entity framework .

My database structure is

```
    CREATE table Registration (
CustomerId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary key,
Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
ContactNo varchar(255) NOT NULL,
EmailId varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Dob varchar(255) NOT NULL,

);
```

and I cretaed the method in in a class library

My Model file is

```
 public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
```

what code i Write in controller to get the value of cutomer in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer [this link](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/create-custom-scaffold-templates-asp-net-mvc/)

> what code i Write in controller to get the value of cutomer in database

you need to create `controller` and `views` to store data to database. I think you are new in `MVC` because `MVC` itself stands for `Model View Controller`.

You have created your model.

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string ContactNo { get; set; }
public string EmailId { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public string Dob { get; set; }
```

But you are missing the `primary key` the `CustomerId`, without this you won't be able to access the corresponding table.

Refer [this site](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/create-custom-scaffold-templates-asp-net-mvc/) for more.